# How to send emails without getting into Spam Act trouble?

Tags: email, spam-prevention

Lets say I have a database of 60,000 emails.

I would like to send them an email notifying them of a new related service (similar to what they've signed up) which adds value to what they already signed up to.

I know most of them would welcome it but they did not opt-in for this new related service. I don't want to send out the email invite only to find out I got into some Spam Act trouble.

What is a friendly way to reach these targetted audience?

Comment: What are you asking for? Legal advice?

Comment: Please. Just. Don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you already send them regular emails about the service they signed up for? If so just include a (short) line in one of those about the new service, and a link to get more. I see that approach with a number of the better organisations I deal with and it isn't one I ever object to (and I'm very strongly anti-spam).